# obtaining upload_dir for Jquery File Upload callback

Tags: jquery, file-upload, path, laravel

Hi I have managed to get the Jquery file upload plugin working within the Laravel framework.

I am able to set the upload_dir which is set as follows in the bundle's config file:

```
return array(
    'upload_dir' => path('storage').'users/',
);
```

This works fine although I need to obtain this URL for the callback in main.js called 'fileuploadcompleted', which will render the uploaded file as HTML:

```
.bind('fileuploadcompleted', function (e, data) {           
        var $filename = $.trim($('#fileupload td.name').text());
        var $filePath = '../bundles/jqueryfileupload/users/';
```

ignore the paths above, they have just been used for testing purposes. So how can I obtain the upload_dir for use in $filePath in the callback above?

Is there a more preferred way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how javascript will be able to render a file given the absolute path of your server's upload directory. Upload dir will look something like this /var/www/vhosts/yoursite.com/storage/users.

You can probably create a route that uses file_get_contents() and your storage directory.

Comment: thanks very much, a route was what I needed here. There is more to my problem than this, though this has helped.